# Irreducibility of the polynomial $a_{n}+a_{n-1}x+\cdots+a_{0}x^{n}$ when irreducibility of $a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n}$ is given

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Given  that  $\mathbb F$  is  a  field  and  $\mathbb F[x]$  is  the  polynomial  ring  over $\mathbb F$.   $\ \ $If  the  polynomial  $a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n}$ is  irreducible  over $\mathbb F[x]$  then  so  is  the  polynomial $a_{n}+a_{n-1}x+a_{n-2}x^{2}+\cdots+a_{0}x^{n}$.

Please  give  me  some  hints  as  to  how  to  begin  to think  the  solution.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: $x^nf(1/x)$ vs. $f(x)$.

Comment: There is the exception that $f(x)=x=1\cdot x+0\cdot1$ is an irreducible polynomial, but $0\cdot x+1\cdot1=1$ is not (because it's a unit of $\Bbb{F}[x]$). Other than this minor exception you can follow the reciprocal route suggested by Gerry, and spelled out in Adayah's answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson :  I  still  don't  get  it . $f(1/x)$   does  not  look  like  a   polynomial  though. Some  more  clue  please.

Comment: $f(1/x)$ doesn't look like a polynomial, because it isn't a polynomial (if the degree of $f$ exceeds zero). But $x^nf(1/x)$ **is** a polynomial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Yes .  But  how  does  that  help  here?  I  mean  $f(x)$  is  irreducible  does  that  imply  that  $x^{n}f(1/x)$   be  so  or  what ?

Comment: If $x^nf(1/x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $g$ of degree $r$, $h$ of degree $s$, $r+s=n$, and then you replace $x$ everywhere with $1/x$, what do you get?

Comment: So, did you try that?

Comment: #GerryMyerson :  Yes. I  got  this . If $x^{n} f(1/x)$=$g(x)f(x)$  then  putting  ${1}\over {x}$ in  place  of  $x$  everywhere ,  it  is ${{1}\over {x^{n}}}f(x)$= $g(1/x)h(1/x)$ , i.e. $f(x)$=$x^{r} g(1/x).x^{s}h(1/x)$  which  gives  non-trivial  factorization  of  $f(x)$ ,  which  is  a  contradiction. So $x^{n} f(1/x)$  cannot  have  non-trivial  factorization. Proved. Right?

Comment: Yes, 118494, you got it. Not all that different from the answer @Adayah posted, if you work through the details. I'd encourage you to either post it as an answer (people are encouraged to post answers to their own questions, when the post has led to their understanding how to answer), or to accept Adayah's answer, if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that

$$a_n + a_{n-1} x + \ldots + a_0 x^n = \left( b_i + b_{i-1} x + \ldots + b_0 x^i \right) \left( c_j + c_{j-1} x + \ldots + c_0 x^j \right).$$

Then what is $\left( b_0 + b_1 x + \ldots + b_i x^i \right) \left( c_0 + c_1 x + \ldots + c_j x^j \right)$ ?